# Should I remove observations causing fitted probability of 0 or 1?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, categorical-data, ordered-logit

I am running an ordinal logistic regression with:

```
adjfit <- MASS::polr(outcome ~ hxcopd + sex + race + age + 
           diabetes + smoke + dyspnea + fnstatus2 + ascites + 
           hxchf + hypermed + renafail + dialysis + steroid + 
           bleeddis + wtloss + lap, data = df`)
```

where `outcome` has 6 possible categories (0 to 5).

This produces an error

```
Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

`fnstatus2` is a factor with three levels:

```
table(df_m$fnstatus2)

Independent Partially dependent   Totally dependent 
    7425                 112                   5
```

All of the `Totally dependent` records have an outcome level of `0`:

```
df %>% dplyr::filter(fnstatus2 == "Totally dependent") %>% 
        dplyr::select(fnstatus2, outcome)

               fnstatus2 outcome
4928   Totally dependent     0
54047  Totally dependent     0
96809  Totally dependent     0
100714 Totally dependent     0
124570 Totally dependent     0
```

When I remove these five records from the dataframe and re-run the analysis, I know longer get the error:

```
df %>% dplyr::filter(fnstatus2 != "Totally dependent")

adjfit2 <- MASS::polr(outcome ~ hxcopd + sex + race + age + 
            diabetes + smoke + dyspnea + fnstatus2 + ascites + 
            hxchf + hypermed + renafail + dialysis + steroid + 
            bleeddis + wtloss + lap, data = df2`)
```

**Should I remove these observations or is this a "false-positive" warning?** It does not seem to have much bearing on the coefficients:

## Without removing observations

```
                                    Value Std. Error    t value
hxcopdTRUE                                0.42863  1.342e-01  3.193e+00
sexTRUE                                  -0.06410  1.940e-01 -3.303e-01
raceAsian                                -1.00369  1.245e+00 -8.063e-01
raceBlack                                 0.22738  1.036e+00  2.195e-01
raceNative Hawaiian or Pacific islander -10.96370  6.278e-05 -1.746e+05
raceWhite                                -0.10687  1.021e+00 -1.046e-01
age                                       0.02040  6.960e-03  2.931e+00
diabetesTRUE                              0.57178  1.670e-01  3.424e+00
smokeTRUE                                 0.16700  1.515e-01  1.103e+00
dyspneaTRUE                               0.17248  1.399e-01  1.233e+00
fnstatus2Partially dependent              0.78438  3.369e-01  2.328e+00
fnstatus2Totally dependent              -14.00459  8.157e-09 -1.717e+09
ascitesTRUE                               1.82496  5.805e-01  3.144e+00
hxchfTRUE                                 0.99521  2.560e-01  3.888e+00
hypermedTRUE                              0.04481  1.508e-01  2.972e-01
renafailTRUE                              0.35707  1.070e+00  3.338e-01
dialysisTRUE                              0.98040  3.492e-01  2.807e+00
steroidTRUE                               0.07941  2.370e-01  3.350e-01
bleeddisTRUE                              0.80356  2.006e-01  4.007e+00
wtlossTRUE                                0.97155  4.148e-01  2.342e+00
lapTRUE                                   0.24056  1.564e-01  1.538e+00

Intercepts:
    Value         Std. Error    t value      
0|1  5.421500e+00  1.156200e+00  4.689200e+00
1|2  5.554000e+00  1.156400e+00  4.802700e+00
2|3  6.074700e+00  1.157800e+00  5.246600e+00
3|4  6.732100e+00  1.160900e+00  5.799100e+00
4|5  7.888900e+00  1.174300e+00  6.718100e+00

Residual Deviance: 2786.892 
AIC: 2838.892
```

## With removing observations

```
                                            Value Std. Error    t value
hxcopdTRUE                                0.42863  1.342e-01  3.193e+00
sexTRUE                                  -0.06409  1.940e-01 -3.303e-01
raceAsian                                -1.00353  1.245e+00 -8.061e-01
raceBlack                                 0.22758  1.036e+00  2.197e-01
raceNative Hawaiian or Pacific islander -10.57520  9.259e-05 -1.142e+05
raceWhite                                -0.10667  1.021e+00 -1.044e-01
age                                       0.02040  6.960e-03  2.932e+00
diabetesTRUE                              0.57178  1.670e-01  3.425e+00
smokeTRUE                                 0.16699  1.515e-01  1.103e+00
dyspneaTRUE                               0.17248  1.399e-01  1.233e+00
fnstatus2Partially dependent              0.78438  3.369e-01  2.328e+00
ascitesTRUE                               1.82500  5.804e-01  3.144e+00
hxchfTRUE                                 0.99521  2.560e-01  3.888e+00
hypermedTRUE                              0.04481  1.508e-01  2.972e-01
renafailTRUE                              0.35708  1.070e+00  3.338e-01
dialysisTRUE                              0.98041  3.492e-01  2.807e+00
steroidTRUE                               0.07942  2.370e-01  3.351e-01
bleeddisTRUE                              0.80355  2.006e-01  4.007e+00
wtlossTRUE                                0.97158  4.148e-01  2.343e+00
lapTRUE                                   0.24055  1.564e-01  1.538e+00

Intercepts:
    Value        Std. Error   t value     
0|1       5.4217       1.1562       4.6891
1|2       5.5542       1.1565       4.8026
2|3       6.0749       1.1579       5.2465
3|4       6.7323       1.1610       5.7989
4|5       7.8891       1.1743       6.7179

Residual Deviance: 2786.892 
AIC: 2836.892
```

What makes me think I *should* remove these observations is because when I attempt to optimize my model with `stepAIC`, the function ends up selecting `fnstatus2Totally Dependent` as a covariate to include with a coefficient that implies being "totally dependent" is actually *strongly favorable* for a patient (which I know, clinically, this makes no sense). But is this just me "looking for the results that I want to see"?

Comment: This is typically solved by penalization techniques. Probabilities 0 or 1 mean perfect separation, which is nice, but algorithm can not deal with it and says that the respective coefficients are infinity, as likelihood function which you are maximizing is not bounded from above (is not concave) ... By adding penalty (LASSO / ridge / ...) you can solve the problem and do not have to remove anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very annoying thing, it's true. Anytime you have a factor level that only has one value of outcome, you can't trust the estimate nor the SE for that factor level. [This resource from UCLA is somewhere that always has nice information for analysis tasks.](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-complete-or-quasi-complete-separation-in-logisticprobit-regression-and-how-do-we-deal-with-them/)

Your approach of removing the observations is sound, but it does mean you need to mention one more thing in your discussion and methods section.

Another way to do it would be simply collapse partially dependent and totally dependent into the same class. You would then be writing about "dependent or independent" in your manuscript. In the methods you would describe what qualifies as "dependence".

Comment: Collapsing the variable is in fact what I had ended up doing. Thank you!